# Gnome Shell extensions cannot be activated

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-shell, shell-extensions

I have several Gnome shell extensions that are suddenly disabled since the last reboot and cannot be enabled. I have not made any changes to the system (not consciously).
All of the extensions worked before.

I see all extensions under extensions.gnome.org.
They can be installed and uninstalled.
They can apparently(!) also be activated/deactivated but in fact they are not activated and after reloading the page you also see that the state of the extension is back in the initial state.

[Screenshot of extensions.gnome.org -> extensions that can't be enabled/disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXPOg.png)

Does anyone have an idea what I could try?
There is not a single error message anywhere.

- OS: Pop 20.10 groovy
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.8.0-7630-generic
- GNOME Shell 3.38.2

The same behavior in Firefox and in Chrome.

This is my first post here.
If something is missing or I can improve something in my request, I am happy to receive suggestions for improvement. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look to Gnome Tweaks. I'm not familiar with PopOS but you can install it with one of the following commands

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

or

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then you can activate the extensions you like:

[image]

Comment: This actually helped solving the problem.
I installed it and by activating the button on the upper right corner, everything started working again.
Somehow the whole extensions-thing was disabled.
Don't know how that happened. 
Now it's working again so thank you very much!! 

Answer (score 6):

On ubuntu 22.04 you may need to start the `extensions` program, and re-enable extensions using the top-right slider.

[image]

Comment: This was the fix for me. Windows Key => "Extensions" => enable => life back to normal. Thx!!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, I needed to `apt install gnome-shell-extensions` (which was missing). This enabled the above behaviour for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Pop! OS is Ubuntu-based, take a look in the [Synaptic Package Manager (SPM)](https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/), which will inform you if packages are damaged or have missing dependencies, and show the [terminal command to repair them](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu-20-04/). The following two I usually find sufficient to fix most issues, and can be run without SPM.

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

See the *Linux Shout* article, above, for more repair suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work because "[...] update does not accept arguments"
But thank you for helping anyway!

Comment: @prebiz there was an issue in code formatting, `–` (en dash) appears instead of `--` (two regular dashes).

Comment: @A.L, thanks for catching that! Some app along the path of cutting and pasting changed that hype to an en-dash, and I'd never have caught the issue, myself.

Answer (score 0):

When an extension is loaded the `dconf` parameter `/org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions` is modified but `dconf` configuration could be locked using:

```
/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks
```

Modify the contained files and then:

```
dconf update
```